# Does creating separate functions instead of one big one slow processing time?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, function, performance

I'm working in the Google App Engine environment and programming in Python.  I am creating a function that essentially generates a random number/letter string and then stores to the memcache.

```
def generate_random_string():
# return a random 6-digit long string

def check_and_store_to_memcache():
    randomstring = generate_random_string()
    #check against memcache
    #if ok, then store key value with another value
    #if not ok, run generate_random_string() again and check again.
```

Does creating two functions instead of just one big one affect performance?  I prefer two, as it better matches how I think, but don't mind combining them if that's "best practice".

Comment: You can indent with 4 spaces for the code to display correctly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Focus on being able to read and easily understand your code.

Once you've done this, if you have a performance problem, then look into what might be causing it.

Most languages, python included, tend to have fairly low overhead for making method calls.  Putting this code into a single function is not going to (dramatically) change the performance metrics - I'd guess that your random number generation will probably be the bulk of the time, not having 2 functions.

That being said, splitting functions does have a (very, very minor) impact on performance.  However, I'd think of it this way - it may take you from going 80 mph on the highway to 79.99mph (which you'll never really notice).  The important things to watch for are avoiding stoplights and traffic jams, since they're going to make you have to stop altogether...

Comment: You didn't mention that premature optimization creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that most languages, python included, tend to have fairly low overhead for making method calls. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Data_Aggregation

Comment: @Swiss: That example is very contrived.  It's doing very little work, in a tight loop, which is a worst case scenario.  In this case, the cost of the function overhead will likely be microscopic when compared to the cost of computing the random and the cost of storing in memcache.  That being said - the overhead of a function call in python is still small, just higher than some other languages - overall, it's still a very minor impact on overall perf., unless your function is doing a trivially small amount of work.

Answer (score 24):

In almost all cases, "inlining" functions to increase speed is like getting a hair cut to lose weight.

Answer (score 4):

Reed is right. For the change you're considering, the cost of a function call is a small number of cycles, and you'd have to be doing it 10^8 or so times per second before you'd notice.

However, I would caution that often people go to the other extreme, and then it is *as if* function calls were costly. I've seen this in over-designed systems where there were many layers of abstraction.

What happens is there is some human psychology that says if something is easy to call, then it is fast. This leads to writing more function calls than strictly necessary, and when this occurs over multiple layers of abstraction, the wastage can be exponential.

Following Reed's driving example, a function call can be like a detour, and if the detour contains detours, and if those also contain detours, soon there is tremendous time being wasted, for no *obvious* reason, because each function call looks innocent.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, I wouldn't worry about it in this particular scenario.  The very small overhead involved in function calls would pale in comparison to what is done inside each function.  And as long as these functions don't get called in rapid succession, it probably wouldn't matter much anyway.

It is a good question though.  In some cases it's best not to break code into multiple functions.  For example, when working with math intensive tasks with nested loops it's best to make as few function calls as possible in the inner loop.  That's because the simple math operations themselves are very cheap, and next to that the function-call-overhead can cause a noticeable performance penalty.

Years ago I discovered the hypot (hypotenuse) function in the math library I was using in a VC++ app was very slow.  It seemed ridiculous to me because it's such a simple set of functionality -- return sqrt(a * a + b * b) -- how hard is that?  So I wrote my own and managed to improve performance 16X over.  Then I added the "inline" keyword to the function and made it 3X faster than that (about 50X faster at this point).  Then I took the code out of the function and put it in my loop itself and saw yet another small performance increase.  So... yeah, those are the types of scenarios where you can see a difference.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sqrt(a*a+b*b) ?