# Delphi and Performance Coding. Statement Performance and code length results

Tags: performance, delphi

Lets simply fantasize and talk about performance.

As I have read the article in about.delphi.com called performance programming, there was interesting paragraphs claiming that Case statement ( in fact I prefer calling it as structure ) is faster than If ; For is faster than While and Repeat, but While is the slowest loop operator. I probably understand why While is the slowest, but ... what about others.

Have you tested / played / experimented or even gained real performance boost if changed, for example, all IF statements to Cases where possible?

Also I would like to talk about other - modified - loop and if statement behaviors in Delphi IDE, but it would be another question.

Shall we start, ladies and gentleman?

Comment: Thanks Lieven for error notification and correction!

Comment: Please provide a link for the article you mention. I find nothing there named "Performance programming."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the best response I've seen to questions like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083105/does-creating-separate-functions-instead-of-one-big-one-slow-processing-time/1085128#1085128)

Answer (score 3):

It's very rare when the type of control structure/loop construct do matter. You can't possibly get any reasonable performance increase if you change, say, `For` loop to `While` loop. Rather, algorithms do matter.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt *for* will be slower in practice than *while*.

AFAIK, *for* evaluates the condition one time while *while* (no pun intended) evaluates the condition every time. Consider following statements

```
for i = 0 to GettingAmountOfUsersIsTakingALotOfTime do
begin
  ...
end;

i := 0;
while i <= GettingAmountOfUsersIsTakingALotOfTime do
begin
  ...
  Inc(I);
end;
```

The while statement will be magnitudes of times slower than the if statement.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct. I did write wrong - I thought the same, but somehow wrote different ;) Anyways - thank you for tip and illustration - I hope it will help othe begginers in Delphi programming ;)